# How to mutate an array of integers in-place in swift through filtering

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering, immutability

One can filter an array like this in swift:

```
var numbers = Array(1...1000000)
numbers = numbers.filter( { return $0 % 2 == 0  } )
```

Is it possible to filter and avoid the copy operation, that occurs when the filtering is done, e.g mutating the original array.

In a similar way to this pseudocode: 
    numbers.MutablefilterOperation({ return $0 % 2 == 0})

In C++ the equvivalent to what is going on in Swift above would be:

```
std::vector<int> originalNumbers(1000000);
std::vector<int> newNumbers;
std::copy_if (originalNumbers.begin(), originalNumbers.end(), std::back_inserter(newNumbers), [](int i) { return i % 2 == 0 } );
```

What I would like to achieve for performance reasons:

```
std::vector<int> originalNumbers(1000000);
auto pos = std::remove_if(originalNumbers.begin(), originalNumbers.end(), [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });
originalNumbers.erase(pos, originalNumbers.end());
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify. Are we talking about an arbitrary Array or one that you generate? If it's arbitrary then any approach will involve looking at each index. If it's generated then you can have a custom generation method to come up with your "filtered" elements.

Comment: What do you find un-clean about your current code? You can always write your own `filterInPlace` method as an extension of `Array` if you really feel strongly about it. Also btw you can write your filter slightly cleaner as `numbers = numbers.filter{$0 % 2 == 0}`

Comment: Or simply `let numbers = Array(1...1000000).filter { $0 % 2 == 0  }`

Comment: I am just curious if it is possible to mutate the array in-place without doing the copy operation, using the standard utilities in Swift

Comment: `Array` is a `struct` which has value semantics, it can't be mutated. Any mutation of it is simply replacing the original.

Comment: `What do you find un-clean about your current code?` It has an operation cost of 2 * O(n) ... you get hit once for the copy O(n) and another for the filter O(n).

Yeah, this reduces to "O(n)" as Big O notation drops scalars, but let's be honest, a factor of 2 _can_ matter.

If Swift provided a `filterInPlace` method out of the box, it would be possible to achieve an actual O(n) runtime.

Comment: I've wondered the same thing. Apple's API Design Guidelines tell us to name non-mutating methods with 'ed' or 'ing' at the end—so we have `sorted()` as the non-mutating counterpart of `sort()`. So why did they ignore their own guidelines when naming `filter()`? Should it not be called `filtered()`?

Comment: It's likely due to the fact that `filter` is a well-established name for the functional algorithm, much in the same way that `map` and `reduce` don't follow the "ed" naming convention.

Answer (score 3):

This implementation should do the filtering without having to make a temporary copy of the entire array in the process (unless a copy of it is referenced by another variable, see "Copy on Write")

```
extension Array {
    mutating func filterInPlace(isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows {
        var writeIndex = self.startIndex
        for readIndex in self.indices {
            let element = self[readIndex]
            let include = try isIncluded(element)
            if include {
                if writeIndex != readIndex {
                    self[writeIndex] = element
                }
                writeIndex = self.index(after: writeIndex)
            }
        }
        self.removeLast(self.distance(from: writeIndex, to: self.endIndex))
    }
}

// example:
var arr = [6,2,6,5,2,5,6,2,2,1,6,7,3]
arr.filterInPlace { $0 % 2 == 1 }
print(arr) // [5, 5, 1, 7, 3]
```